# Memory leak in linked list using dynamic allocation for deleting elements

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, linked-list

I have been working on a linked list problem, using two pointers to the head and the tail of the list respectively. The issue I have is the following:

When I want to remove from the front or the back of the list, I get memory leaks when the corresponding class methods are implemented using temporary dynamically allocated node pointer and I can't find out what exactly is the problem that is causing the leak.

```
#include <iostream>

class Node {
   public:
      Node():data(0),ptrNode(nullptr){};
      ~Node() {};

      // declaring the getters and setters
      float getData() const {return data;};
      void setData(float d) {data = d;};
      Node* getNodePtr() const {return ptrNode;};
      void setNodePtr(Node* n){ptrNode = n;};

   private:
      float data;
      Node* ptrNode;
    };


class List {

   private:
      Node * ptrHead;
      Node * ptrTail;


   public:
      List():ptrHead(nullptr),ptrTail(nullptr) {};
      ~List() {};

      void insertAtFront(float x) {
               Node * temp = new Node();
               temp->setData(x);

               if (ptrHead == nullptr) {
                     ptrHead = temp;
                     ptrTail = temp;
               } else {
                     temp->setNodePtr(ptrHead);
                     ptrHead = temp;
               }
      };

      void insertAtBack(float x) {
               Node * temp = new Node();
               temp->setData(x);

               if (ptrHead == nullptr) {
                     ptrHead = temp;
                     ptrTail = temp;
               } else {
                     ptrTail->setNodePtr(temp);
                     ptrTail = temp;
               }
      };

      void removeFromFront() {

               if (ptrHead==nullptr) {  // if list is empty
                    std::cout << "List is already empty" << std::endl;
                    return;
               }

               if (ptrHead==ptrTail) { // if list has one element
                    delete ptrHead;
                    ptrHead = nullptr;
                    ptrTail = nullptr;
                    return;
               }
               // assign current Head to temp, assign next node to head 
               // delete temp
               Node * temp = new Node();
               temp = ptrHead;
               ptrHead = ptrHead->getNodePtr();
               delete temp;
               temp = nullptr;
      };

      void removeFromBack() {

               if (ptrHead==nullptr) {  // if list is empty
                    std::cout << "List is already empty" << std::endl;
                    return;
               }

               if (ptrHead==ptrTail) { // if list has one element
                    delete ptrHead;
                    ptrHead = nullptr;
                    ptrTail = nullptr;
                    return;
               }

               // create two temp Node pointers for this one
               Node * sec2last = new Node();
               Node * last = new Node();

               sec2last = ptrHead;
               last = ptrTail;

               // locate second to last element and assign it to sec2last
               while (sec2last->getNodePtr() != ptrTail) {
                     sec2last = sec2last->getNodePtr();
               }

               ptrTail = sec2last;
               ptrTail->setNodePtr(nullptr);

               delete last;
               delete sec2last;
               last = nullptr;
               sec2last = nullptr;
      };

   };
```

I run the following in main():

```
// global function that dynamically allocates memory in its scope
// for a linked list
void generateList(int x) {
   if (x<=0) {
      cout << "Give a positive integer!" << endl;
      return;
   }

   List * aList = new List();

   for (int i = 0;i<x;i++) {
      aList->insertAtFront(i+1);
   }

   aList->removeFromBack();  // this causes leaks

   delete aList;
}

// MAIN
int main() {

   for (int i = 0;i<80000000;i++)    
       generateList(1);   // just repeatedly generate dynamic list 
                          // with one element
   return 0;
}
```

I should point out that if we don't use dynamically allocate memory for the temporary nodes within the removeFromFront() and removeFromBack() methods, then the program works fine. But, like I said, It kills me that I can't see why we have leaks with the code above.

Thanks!

Comment: You're allocating stuff and then immediately discarding the value, like with `Node * temp = new Node();  temp = ptrHead`.

Comment: `Node* getNodePtr() const {return ptrNode;};` is problematic (in theory). You couldn't build up a truely const list this way. Typically, you'd solve it by returning a pointer to const (so if first list element is const, next one is const, too) - and to be able to modify the list, you'd provide a non-const overload returning a non-const pointer. However, the node class is intended to be used within list only, so I'd rather make it a private nested class of your list class. You don't need access control then, so you could skip the getters and just make the members public...

Comment: ... *unless* you intend to use the Node class as iterator as well. Then: let node be a public, but *still nested* class of your list and provide public access to the value; have a public `operator++` hopping to next node, but keep the node pointer private - without getters/setters (user shall not modify the list). List class itself then would need to be a friend of node, so it and only it has access to the pointer to modify it.

Comment: Thanks for the answers! Also, good point Aconcagua.

Answer (score 5):

```
           Node * temp = new Node();
           temp = ptrHead;
```

This is a memory leak right here. You allocate a new `Node` and store a pointer to it in `temp`. Then you overwrite that pointer and leak the node you just allocated.

```
           // create two temp Node pointers for this one
           Node * sec2last = new Node();
           Node * last = new Node();

           sec2last = ptrHead;
           last = ptrTail;
```

And here you do it again. Why are you allocating new `Node`s here?

Comment: Thanks! I thought this might cause the problem. I guess I was expecting to somehow overcome the leaks by initializing Node data members to null, but I guess even in that case, you still have an allocated address that just contains a Node with null data members. Is there a way to do it though by using dynamic allocation within the List methods? 
Like I said in my post, I have a working version of it where I just use automatic allocation, which is fine, but I just wondered if this can be done this way without leaks.

Comment: @chlyr314 Why not just `Node* temp = ptrHead;` or `Node* temp; temp=ptrHead;`? Why do you do `new Node()` when you don't want a new node?